# How to Upload files from a multidimension array

Tags: php, mysql

Could someone please help me. I am trying to update the file in MYSQL DB and move the uploaded file to a folder "upload/documents/" but i cant seem to get the file in docUpload.  i keep getting this Notice: Undefined index: 'docfile' in C:. Can anyone please help me. This is a var_dump of my $_files:

```
    Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [1001] => Array
                    (
                        [101] => Array
                            (
                                ['docUpload'] => test.txt
                            )

                        [1010] => Array
                            (
                                ['docUpload'] => test 2.txt
                            )

                    )

                [901] => Array
                    (
                        [701] => Array
                            (
                                ['docUpload'] => test 3.txt
                            )

                        [901] => Array
                            (
                                ['docUpload'] => 
                            )

                    )

            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [1001] => Array
                    (
                        [101] => Array
                            (
                                ['docUpload'] => text/plain
                            )

                        [1010] => Array
                            (
                                ['docUpload'] => text/plain
                            )

                    )

                [901] => Array
                    (
                        [701] => Array
                            (
                                ['docUpload'] => text/plain
                            )

                        [901] => Array
                            (
                                ['docUpload'] => 
                            )

                    )

            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [1001] => Array
                    (
                        [101] => Array
                            (
                                ['docUpload'] => C:\xampp\tmp\php16C8.tmp
                            )

                        [1010] => Array
                            (
                                ['docUpload'] => C:\xampp\tmp\php16C9.tmp
                            )

                    )

                [901] => Array
                    (
                        [701] => Array
                            (
                                ['docUpload'] => C:\xampp\tmp\php16CA.tmp
                            )

                        [901] => Array
                            (
                                ['docUpload'] => 
                            )

                    )

            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [1001] => Array
                    (
                        [101] => Array
                            (
                                ['docUpload'] => 0
                            )

                        [1010] => Array
                            (
                                ['docUpload'] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [901] => Array
                    (
                        [701] => Array
                            (
                                ['docUpload'] => 0
                            )

                        [901] => Array
                            (
                                ['docUpload'] => 4
                            )

                    )

            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [1001] => Array
                    (
                        [101] => Array
                            (
                                ['docUpload'] => 0
                            )

                        [1010] => Array
                            (
                                ['docUpload'] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [901] => Array
                    (
                        [701] => Array
                            (
                                ['docUpload'] => 0
                            )

                        [901] => Array
                            (
                                ['docUpload'] => 0
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

here is what i have done so far:

```
        $producySelected = $_FILES['docUpload']; 
        if(!empty($producySelected))
        {
            $icount = 0;
            foreach($producySelected as $key=>$selected)
            {
                $icompte = 0;
                foreach($selected as $keyz=>$value)
                {
                    echo "<pre>";
                    echo($key);
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo($keyz);
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo ($value["'docUpload'"]); ??
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "</pre>";
                $icompte++; 
                }
            $icount++;
            }
        }
```